# Drop resistant iPhone 6 battery case

Tags: case, apple

I drop my iPhone 6 a lot but also need that extended battery and wired headphones.

Is there a life proof that has a battery or that fits on top of the Apple Battery Case?  Alternatively a battery case that is near indestructible.

EDIT: So this question was originally about iPhone 7, but I have edited to be the iPhone 6s/6(so that I could answer the question) with my solution.

Comment: No idea if it's any good, but the SnowLizard SLXtreme looks interesting.

Comment: Yes except I believe you have to use wireless headphones.

Comment: If you're concerned about that again, you should've just made this an edit to your previous post rather than creating a new one.

Comment: There are technically  different.  This doesnt need to be waterproof just shatterproof.

Comment: previous question similar but different https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8843/iphone-7-waterpoof-battery-case-with-music

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @JMY1000 Snow Lizard has shutdown unfortunately.  :( I love my iPhone 6 set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up buying a 6s for now and buying a SnowLizard 6 case for the phone.  The battery is excellent with the case and I can plug my on headphones in when needed.